# Assigning a set value of integers 1 value in mysql

Tags: sql

How do I assign, say, integers 1-10 value "x" and integers 11-20 value "y" without creating 20 different entries?

For example, if you are buying a concert ticket, and you are assigned integer 2, you will sit in row 3. likewise, if you are assigned integer 9, you will also sit in row 3. however, integer 13 will sit in row 5, as will integer 19.
the integers assigned are purposely assigned, and some integers may be skipped (They are not consecutive).

Comment: Add a little more info to the question, what do you mean by assign? update? insert? Some examples are always helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET row = CASE WHEN number <= 10 THEN 3
               WHEN number <= 20 THEN 5
               WHEN number <= 30 THEN 4
               ...
          END
```